# String.Format DateTime value in decreasing number format c#?

Tags: c#

```
DateTime input = DateTime.Now; //06/02/2011 04:05:07 PM
expectedOutput string = "20110602040507";
```

I want to get the above output string based on date following this ( year,month,day,hour,minute,second) pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the format string "yyyyMMddHHmmss", which will give hours in 24-hour format.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) method:

```
String format = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
String formattedValue = input.ToString(format);
```